# Promise bluebird with multiple classes response

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Im trying to make request to url and parse XML data after that request and print result but I keep getting `undefined` instead of result, what I'm doing wrong?

```
var parseUrl = 'url which returns XML as response';
    var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
    var xml2js = Promise.promisify(require('xml2js').parseString);
    Promise.promisifyAll([request, xml2js]);

    request({url: parseUrl, json: true}).then(function(data){
        if (data.body){
            return data.body;
        } else {
            return error.throw('Failed to parse body from response');
        }
    }).then(function(data){
        xml2js(data, function(err, result){
            if (!err){
                return result;
            } else {
                return error.throw('Failed to read converted body from response');
            }
        });
    }).then(function(data){
        console.warn(data);
    }).catch(function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    });
```

Comment: You specify `json: true` but expect XML in `data.body`. Is that right?

Comment: That would be somewhat unconventional.

Comment: You must pass no callback to the promisified `xml2js`, and more importantly you need to `return` its result promise from the `then` callback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because xml2js already promisifiсation.

2) You do not need to use Promise.promisifyAll

```
var parseUrl = 'url which returns XML as response';
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
var xml2js = Promise.promisify(require('xml2js').parseString);

request({url: parseUrl, json: true})
  .then(function(data){
    if (data.body){
        return data.body;
    } else {
        return error.throw('Failed to parse body from response');
    }
}).then(xml2js)
  .then(function(data){
    console.warn(data);
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e.message);
});
```

Comment: Not sure if intentional but just want to point out that this can be simplified to  `request(...).then(xml2js).then(console.warn).catch(function(e) { console.log(e.message); });`